# Getting very slow execution time for a postgresql query

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I did the explain analyze for this query, it was giving 30ms, but if the data is more I will get an execution expired; Using PostgreSQL 10

For normal execution: https://explain.depesz.com/s/gSPP

For slow execution: https://explain.depesz.com/s/bQN2

```
SELECT inventory_histories.*, order_items.order_id as order_id FROM
"inventory_histories" LEFT JOIN order_items ON (order_items.id = 
inventory_histories.reference_id AND inventory_histories.reference_type = 4) 
WHERE "inventory_histories"."inventory_id" = 1313 AND 
(inventory_histories.location_id = 15) ORDER BY inventory_histories.id DESC 
LIMIT 10 OFFSET 0;
```

Indexes:

```
"inventory_histories_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
"inventory_histories_created_at_index" btree (created_at)
"inventory_histories_inventory_id_index" btree (inventory_id)
"inventory_histories_location_id_index" btree (location_id)
```

Comment: PostgreSQL <> MySQL. I have removed the irrelevant tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this query:

```
SELECT ih.*, oi.order_id as order_id
FROM "inventory_histories" ih LEFT JOIN
     order_items oi
     ON oi.id = ih.reference_id AND
        ih.reference_type = 4 
WHERE ih."inventory_id" = 1313 AND 
      ih.location_id = 15
ORDER BY ih.id DESC 
LIMIT 10 OFFSET 0;
```

For this query, you want composite indexes on `inventory_histories(inventory_id, location_id, id, reference_id)` and on `order_items(id, reference_type, order_id)`.

Comment: If i add an index for multiple columns and if any query is calling related to one column, that time also that index will work right?

Comment: @django . . . I don't understand your comment.  A multi-column index can be used for queries that don't use all the columns.  The columns get used from left to right.

Comment: For example  i added index for this inventory_histories
(inventory_id, location_id, id, reference_id) 
and if i am calling the query is "select * from inventory_histories where inventory_id = 2 and location_id = 55" so this time that index will work? because we added that for 3 columns right?

Comment: oh sorry man, i think i misunderstood, you were saying  i have to add the index for all these columns (inventory_id, location_id, id, reference_id) separately right?

Comment: Also why do we need to add index for reference_type in order_items, i don't have that field in that table

Comment: I added index for all these columns in two tables, still its same

Comment: @django - An index on `(a, b, c)` is Not the same as three indexes `(a)` and `(b)` and `(c)`.  Imagine a spreadsheet, and you order it by the columns `a, then b, then c`.  Only it's a binarytree instead of a spread sheet.  It's too big a topic for a comment or even a SO Question and Answer.  You need to search online for tutorials on indexing strategies in SQL and PostgreSQL in particular.

Comment: @django - Please update your question with the indexes you created, and ideally the new explain plan for your query.

Comment: sure @MatBailie, but what is this order_items(id, reference_type, order_id), because i don't have any field like reference_type in order_items table

Comment: It's just a typo.  Use `inventory_histories(inventory_id, location_id, id, reference_type, reference_id)` and `order_items(id, order_id)`

Comment: ok i have added multiple column indexes inventory_histories(inventory_id, location_id, id, reference_id), so that has reduced to 1, one more thing i have to ask you , is it ok to adding index as it is a big database?

Comment: @djano - If adding indexes to big databases was a universally bad idea, they'd be pointless.